# Positive root of a polynomial

Tags: polynomials

Is anything in general known about the **positive** root $x_{+}$ of the following polynomial of degree $(n+1)$, as a function of the coefficients $\alpha_{1}, \alpha_{2}, ..., \alpha_{n} > 0$:

$$\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(1 - x^{2}\alpha_{i}\right)\prod_{j=1\\j\neq i}^{n}\left(1 + x\alpha_{j}\right) = 0.$$

Is this polynomial well-known? At this point, I know that $x_{+}$ is unique, but would like to know its dependence on $\alpha_{i}>0, i=1,...,n$.

Of course, I can employ root-finding algorithms, but currently my focus is understanding the qualitative nature of $x_{+}$. [I could not even tackle $n=2$ case.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2105258/positive-root-of-2ab-x3-ab-x2-abx-2-0)

Please tag as appropriate.

Comment: How do you know it is unique?

Comment: I know it two ways. First: the above polynomial is the first order optimality condition for a convex optimization problem over $x>0$. Second: if you break down the products in the above polynomial and use the fact that $\alpha_{i}>0$, then you will see that the only change in sign occurs from the $x^n$ term to the $x^{n-1}$th term. Then by Descartes' rule of sign, the number of positive roots is exactly one.

Answer (score 4):

Not a full answer, but some comments and an algorithm that the OP may find relevant.

Assuming $x \not= -1/\alpha_1,\ldots,-1/\alpha_n$, we can rewrite the equation as
\begin{equation*}
\prod_j (1+x\alpha_j)\sum_i \frac{(1-x^2\alpha_i)}{1+x\alpha_i} = 0.
\end{equation*}
Under our assumption, this further simplifies to the OP's [older equation:](https://mathoverflow.net/q/259875/8430)
\begin{equation*}
f(x) := \sum_i \frac{1-x^2\alpha_i}{1+x\alpha_i}=0.
\end{equation*}
Perhaps at this point, you could try to: (i) bracket the root, obtaining points $a<x^*<b$ such that $f(a)<0$, $f(x^*)=0$ and $f(b)>0$, where the bounds are reasonable functions of the $\alpha_i$; (ii) run (by hand) an iteration or two of Newton's method to get an approximate $x^*$ (seems hard); (iii) try [Lagrange inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem); or (iv) try a fixed-point iteration.

---

*Example of (iv).* Rewrite the equation as follows
\begin{equation*}
x^2\sum_i \frac{\alpha_i}{1+x \alpha_i} = \sum_i \frac{1}{1+x\alpha_i}.
\end{equation*}
Using the notation $a(x)=\sum_i \alpha_i/(1+x \alpha_i)$ and $b(x)=\sum_i 1/(1+x \alpha_i)$, we then solve for $x$ by running the iteration
\begin{equation*}
 x_{k+1} = [b(x_k)/a(x_k)]^{1/2},\quad k=0,1,\ldots.
\end{equation*}
An experiment suggests that started from $x_0=0$, this iteration monotonically increases $x$ (*some calculation required, but one can show this easily*). Since $b(x)/a(x)$ is bounded above, the sequence $(x_k)$ must converge. Using a couple of steps of this iteration, one can get a "reasonable" approximation to the the desired solution $x^*$ (this seems to converge quite fast, so could be a reasonable method to solve for $x$ numerically too).

---

<s>*EDIT*: It seems that this Fixed-Point Iteration (FPI) is used in [the preprint](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.08157.pdf) authored by the OP (albeit, without attribution)!</s>

**EDIT 2**: Meanwhile (as noted in the comments below) the OP has *fixed the attribution*; please check the link the his comment for the latest version.

Comment: any reason you would prefer numerically solving the rational equation rather than the polynomial?

Comment: Not really; I just wrote it back in this form as it seems more amenable to points (i) and (iii) above.

Comment: @AbhishekHalder Since the rational equation has poles, it is easier to bracket the roots.

Comment: It seems an interesting exercise to prove monotonicity of the iteration that I wrote up there; by differentiating the map $b(x)/a(x)$ it is easy to verify for small $n$; the general case works out quite nicely without using differentiation, actually. I'll type up the details when I get some time!

Comment: @Suvrit: I know it's bit late to ask, but do you recall how did you prove monotonicity without using differentiation?

Comment: If I recall correctly, you can directly show it by choosing $x < y$ and computing  $b(x)/a(x)- b(y)/a(y)$, which is rather close of course to computing derivatives.

Comment: @AbhishekHalder I saw that you wrote a preprint https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.08157.pdf which seems to use the above FPI, but your preprint contains no link to MO nor any acknowledgment? am I missing something?

Comment: FPI stands for fixed-point iteration?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Yes, indeed, FPI stands for fixed-point iteration (sorry for sloppy usage!)

Comment: @Suvrit: Thanks for pointing that out. I have just updated the arxiv submission with an acknowledgement section with citations and MO link. Sorry it took a while to figure out how to cite MO in a paper.

Comment: The updated version is now available: https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.08157

Comment: @Suvrit: It has been 1.5 months since my last comment. Yet your post's EDIT does not reflect or acknowledge my attribution. What am I missing here?

Comment: @AbhishekHalder Please note the original omission to cite was yours, not mine. I just did not get a chance to update this answer since then, and since the comment thread below it completes the picture, the delay in 're-EDITING' is not too severe imo, hence you are not missing anything -- I am a little surprised at your somehwat aggressive comment though.

Comment: @Suvrit: Thanks a lot. I just wanted to clarify that immediately after my first arxiv submission (which was hasty, I admit, should have figured out how to cite MO before doing that), I updated the manuscript with attribution. It is just that it took 4 days till Mar 28 for the updated arxiv version to appear. Anyway, I kept feeling uncomfortable with the glaring "without attribution" comment staying there for some time. Just my feeling.